# Multiple histograms with logarithmic x scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is a combination of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453570/opacity-misleading-when-plotting-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib) on multiple histograms, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855710/how-to-have-logarithmic-bins-in-a-python-histogram) on a logarithmic scales.

I am trying to have two (or more) histograms in a plot with a logarithmic x-scale, using this code: (with some external lists)

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist([capacity_list, capacity_list2], np.logspace(-1,4,11))
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

It works in principle; my only problem is that the logarithmic scale also seems to affect the bin width of the histograms and so one if them always has shorter bins, which doesn't look nice:

[image: two histograms with logarithmic x-axis]

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: I think you would be better off using one of the other styles of histogram (like `step`) as the offset and shrinking of the bars is actually very misleading in this case.  The 'stacked' variaty of histograms might also be good here.

Comment: Have you tried using `np.histogram` and then plotting a bar plot ?

Comment: @tcaswell using step is a good idea, that also works for what I want. Stacked is not so good since it makes it harder to compare the sizes of the bins visually.

Comment: @hashcode55 I looked into it using this [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) documentation, but couldn't get it to work. Also it says that matplotlib passes the arguments for histograms to np.histogram anyways, so not sure it would make a difference